# Autofill formula needed

Tags: excel

I would like to create a formula where if someone was to answer "YES" in column A then the number "1" would autofill in column B on the same line.  If they answer "NO" I would like it to then have the "0" appear in column B instead.  Could someone help me with a formula for this?   Thank you!

Comment: In B1: `=IF(A1="YES",1,IF(A1="NO",0,""))` and copy down the length of the desired data set.

Comment: Thanks so much Scott!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version of @Scott's solution:

```
=--(A1="YES")
```

Assumes no blanks in ColumnA.